# PHP text formating using define function

Tags: php

I need to display some text using define, but the text includes newlines. When I enter the text as an argument, it is not displayed with the newlines. Is there any way to fix this?

define('TEXT_INFORMATION', 'place for the text');

Thank you

Comment: define is for defining a constant, and defining a constant doesn't display it. so can you be more clear?

Comment: html new lines are `<br>` usually

Comment: use heredoc http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: define('TEXT_INFORMATION', "place for\nthe text");

Comment: Do you mean 'line breaks' rather than 'new lines'?

Comment: What is your definition of newlines? (\n or \r\n ?) Do you mean that html does not include <br /> Give us an example of the text?

Answer (score 2):

**Use nl2br**
( http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php )

It replaces the newlines (\n, \r, \n\r, \r\n) to breaks ( `<br />` )

```
/* Little Example */
define('TEXT_INFORMATION', 'Line 1
Line 2
Line 3');

echo nl2br(TEXT_INFORMATION);
```

Comment: isn't it easier to just put the `<br/>` directly into the string?

Comment: Absolutely, but I can think of many cases where the user puts data in the define ( for example if the user can change languages ) and many users have never heard from `<br/>`

Comment: Hmm, a constant set from user input isn't erm constant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
define('TEXT_INFORMATION', nl2br(<<<EOD
This is a text
with multiple lines
EOD
));
```

Comment: If it is needed to display newlines correctly in html, `<pre>...</pre>` tag can be used. As the question was about PHP part, I didn't noted that.

Answer (score 1):

In order for PHP to recognise escape characters you need to use double quotes:-

```
define('TEXT_INFORMATION', "Place for text<br/>\n");
echo TEXT_INFORMATION;
```

See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for more information on using escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

try

> define("TEXT_INFORMATION", "place for the text \n");

http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/phpTutorial/quotes.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put in newlines you can use \r and \n (and \r\n). Though I think you'd have to use "" for \r and \n to work.
You can also use nl2br to have the newlines be converted to 
 tags.